# Charge transmission coefficient

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-transport

Suppose the left lead, right lead and the scattering region are all the same metallic system; such as iron. Why is the charge transimission coefficient must be a positive integer number at any fermi energy level?

How is the charge transimission coefficient related to the number of corssing points between the fermi energy level and the eigen state in the band structure?

Would anyone please give me some suggestions?

Thank you in advance.